# Page not rendering when I import "Paper-input"

Tags: polymer

The problem I am having here is that the page renders fine when I do not import "paper-input". But when I import "Paper-input" the page does not render. I have not tested any other imports at the moment to see if the page renders. Any ideas why it doesn't render? I've just tried using the imports from the polymer website such as "" and it does not work. Also I have created a test file using all imports starting with the http and it seems to work fine. I do prefer to have the imports locally on my server instead of using the online sources.

```
<!--Header & Tabs -->
<link rel="import" href="../components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<!-- Input text box -->
<link rel="import" href="../components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<!-- Font -->
<link rel="import" href="../components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
<script src="../components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>  

<body unresolved>

    <core-header-panel>
        <core-toolbar>
            <paper-tabs id="tabs" selected="0" self-end>
                <paper-tab name="first">first</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab name="second">second</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab name="third">third</paper-tab>
            </paper-tabs>
        </core-toolbar>
    </core-header-panel>

    <!-- input box -->
    <paper-input label="Name" ></paper-input>

</body>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the JS console? Do you see errors in the network tab of Chorme/Firefox developer tools?

Comment: Has any solution been found to this ? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: the only solution that i found is by importing the complete link which is a bad idea incase if the link does get shutdown.  for example 

to import paper-button i would import

http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html